# To how many bluetooth receptors can I send sound from my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth

I have two 2.1 surrounds system at home and I would like to pair both with my MacBook via bluetooth to play at the same time. Is that possible? In that case, what should I look for?

I did a little research and found that a mac can pair up to 7 devices (in the link that follow this message). But it doesn't answer my question. http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3887#howmany

Some idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: so what is your question then?

Comment: @Buscar: My question is on the topic ;) To how many bluetooth receptors can I send sound from my MacBook (at the same time)?Is that possible? In that case, what should I look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used aggregation to play sound via Bluetooth and wired audio at the same time. I originally used soundflower. But you can use apples AudioMIDI app which does the same thing.

Apple have instruction here.

[How to combine multiple audio interfaces by creating an aggregate device](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3956)

Which basically shows you how to create a single output selection that sends the output to more than one device.

I am unable to test this against multiple Bluetooth devices but think if there is any way to do it then this would be it.